# Rails + Ajax: destroy.js.erb rendered successfully but div (with specific id) is not being removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to create a feature where user can click an unfollow button to destroy a friendship through ajax, however, the div is not removed even though console says destroy.js.erb was rendered with success. Desired outcome: When user clicks unfollow, the record is removed from followers page. My code seems logical to me, would someone be able to point out to me where I have gone wrong?

**friendship/destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#following following_<%= @follow.id %>').remove();
$('#following h3').html("You are following <%= pluralize(current_user.active_friends.count, 'person') %>");


class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
      @friendship = Friendship.find_by(id: params[:id])
      @follow = @friendship.friend
      if @friendship.destroy
        if @friendship.accepted? == true
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to followers_path, :flash => { :success =>  "You have unfollowed #{@friendship.user.name}."} }
            format.js 
          end
        else
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to followers_path, :flash => { :success =>  "You have declined #{@friendship.user.name}'s follow request."} }
            format.js  
          end
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry! Could not unfollow user/decline follow request!"
        redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
      end
    end

end
```

**users/following.html.erb  (page showing a list of users being followed)**

```
<div class = "container" id="following">
  <h3 class = "padding-bottom-40">You are following <%= pluralize(@following.count, 'person') %></h3>
  <% @following.each do |follow| %>
    <div class="row alternate-row" id ="#following_<%= follow.id %>">
      <div class = "col-md-1 col-xs-2">
        <%= gravatar_for(follow, size: 45) %>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-9 col-xs-6">
        <b><%= link_to follow.name, user_path(follow) %></b><br>
        <p><%= pluralize(follow.articles.count, "article") if follow.articles %></p>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-xs-4">
        <%= link_to "Unfollow", friendship_path(current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(follow.id)), :method => :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class:"btn btn-md btn-danger" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Users controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def following
    @following = current_user.active_friends.all
  end

end
```

**schema:**

User is the person who submitted the follow request, Friend is the person who the user wants to follow.

```
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.boolean "accepted", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: u using # in id attribute

Comment: @krishnar hi, i have tried that too before, but it doesn't fix the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the id attribute:

```
<div class="row alternate-row" id="following_<%= follow.id %>">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
let one = $('#one')
let two = $('#two')
console.log(one.attr('id'))
console.log(two.attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="#two"></div>
```

Comment: In your view @diana, not in the js file, you need the `#` to specify you're getting an element by its id.